# Automating tasks in Clojure

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, leiningen

I have the following in my **project.clj**

```
:aliases {
        "start-server" ["ring" "server-headless"]
        "build-site" ["run" "-m" "cjohansen-no.web/export"]
        "build-html" ["run" "-m" "cjohansen-no.web/export-pages"]
        "build-prod" ["do" ["build-site"] ["cljsbuild" "once" "prod"]]
        "build-js" ["cljsbuild" "auto" "dev"]
        "watch-stuff" [ "do" ["start-server"] ["auto" "build-html"]]
        "build-dev" ["do" ["build-site"] ["build-js"] ["watch-stuff"]]
            }
  :clean-targets [:target-path "./build/js/out"
                  :compile-path "classes"
                  :output-paths "./build/js/output"
                  "build/js/main.js.map"
                  ]
  :auto {"build-html" {:file-pattern #"\.(clj|hiccup)$" :paths ["src" "resources"]}}
  :clean-non-project-classes true
  :cljsbuild {
    :builds [{
      :id "dev"
      :source-paths ["src/cljs"]
      ; :figwheel {
      ;   :http-server-root "build"
      ;   :css-dirs ["resources/public/css"]
      ; }
      :compiler {
             :main scripts.core,
             :output-to "build/js/main.js",
             :output-dir "build/js/out",
             :optimizations :none,
             :source-map true,
             :source-map-timestamp true,
             :recompile-dependents false
           }
      },
      {
        :id "prod"
        :source-paths ["src/cljs"]
        :compiler {
               :main scripts.core,
               :output-to "build/js/main.js",
               :output-dir "build/js/output"
               :optimizations :simple,
               :source-map "build/js/main.js.map",
               :asset-path "js/out"
               :pretty-print true
             }
        }
      ]
  }
```

I'm trying to automate my build by using aliases but don't seem to have it quite together...

running `lein build-dev` gets everything going except the "watch-stuff" which runs a [lien-auto] plugin and ring server but the it doesn't seem to function.

in the build output the last thing that happens is

> Watching for changes before compiling ClojureScript...
>   Compiling "build/js/main.js" from ["src/cljs"]...
>   WARNING: test already refers to: cljs.core/test being replaced by: > scripts.core/test at line 5 src/cljs/scripts/core.cljs
>   Successfully compiled "build/js/main.js" in 4.54 seconds.

is there anything stopping this? how do I automate this in clojure?

**Update**

I've been moving stuff around and it seems that in some instances the specific task usually enters into its process....not sure if this causes the task executing afterwards to be suspended...does it?

e.g. if "ring" "server-headless" runs before "build-site" build-site does get run...

How do I then pass through the task and go on to the next one?

P.S. Gulp and Grunt was never this hard *sigh*

Comment: You should use [Boot](http://boot-clj.com/). :)

Comment: shameless plug @SamEstep ???

Comment: No, I've contributed [very little code](https://github.com/boot-clj/boot/pull/434) to Boot itself. All I'm saying is that it's a good build tool that's well-suited to what you're trying to do.

Comment: Looks a bit out of my league for a noob

Comment: Why are you shadowing the function `cljs.core/test` with your own in the `scripts.core` namespace?

Comment: not even sure that that means @ChrisDevo

Comment: @Kendall You have created a function `scripts.core/test`. There is already a function named `test` in `cljs.core`. It is usually a bad idea to reuse names of functions in the core Clojure libraries. There are ways to avoid this collision, but primarily you should just avoid using those names of functions already present in the language.